# Custom Background for Multi Line Text Field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a background for my text field in Flutter.
I need a multi-line text field in which, when the user wants to go to the next line, a space between the lines is created, resulting in one text field with a separate background for each line.
Something similar to this example :

[image]